# Formatting any string to tax ID format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formatting

I can format a string to SSN format or tax ID format if the string is all numbers (ex. 123456789). But for security reasons, the data that will be sent to the UI will be encrypted and will look like this (*****6789).

I am currently doing the formatting like this:

```
var taxID = "123456789", formatSpecifier, regex;

regex = RegExp(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/);
formatSpecifier = "$1 - $2 - $3";

taxID = taxID.replace(regex, formatSpecifier);
taxID = taxID.substring(0, taxID.length - 4).replace(/[a-z\d]/gi,"*") + taxID.substring(taxID.length - 4, taxID.length);

return taxID;
```

Now this will return the taxID like this: **** - ** - 1234

But I'm not just getting the same output if the string contains asterisks. I'm not familiar with regex and this is mostly what I can find in formatting ssn numbers. Im using angularjs/javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) for angularjs it is meant for your purpose. Also here is another way using formatter function if you are not having display as input 
https://jsfiddle.net/V6GN5/486/`jsfiddle`